# Twitter Bootstrap Click Between Tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to add a clickable link at the bottom of a Twitter Bootstrap tab, that will then go to the next named tab, and go back to the top and show the next tab selected (as if the user had clicked on the tab at the top of the page)?

I added a link to do what the tab click does - it swaps the tab content, but does not show the tab selection changing within the tab itself - and also leaves you at the bottom of the page.  This is the link I added:

```
 <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Technical Test</a>
```

This is the whole HTML:

```
    <div class="tabbable">
        <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">PC Phone Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Technical Test</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
               <!-- tab 1 content here -->

               <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Technical Test</a>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
               <!-- tab 2 content here -->
            </div>
         </div>
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

After finding something similar, I came up with:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#TestClick").click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
            var tabs = $('#tabselect .nav-tabs > li'),
               active = tabs.filter('.active'),
               next = active.next('li'),
               toClick = next.length ? next.find('a') : tabs.eq(0).find('a');

            toClick.trigger('click');
            $("#Q1KH").focus();
        });

    });
```

Probably not very elegant - but correctly set the tab, and focussed on the textbox at the top of the screen.

Thanks, Mark